# Is there any function in dax to find string like in SQL ( Like 'string%')

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I'm looking for a DAX function in which I can find a string in column like what we do in Sql by using like operator i.e.  where itemed like ('ABC%')

Answer (score 6):

there is no like operator, but we can use some usefull combination.

| SQL | DAX |
| --- | --- |
| Name LIKE 'SQLBI' | Table[Name] = "SQLBI" |
| Name LIKE 'SQLBI%' | LEFT( Table[Name], 5 ) = "SQLBI" |
| Name LIKE '%SQLBI' | RIGHT( Table[Name], 5 ) = "SQLBI" |
| Name LIKE '%SQLBI%' | CONTAINSSTRING( Table[Name], "SQLBI" ) |
|  | for PowerPivot v2 or later and Analysis Services 2012/2014/2016/2017: |
|  | SEARCH( "SQLBI", Table[Name], 1, 0 ) > 0 |
|  | for PowerPivot v1: |
|  | IFERROR( SEARCH( "SQLBI", Table[Name], 1 ), 0 ) > 0 |
| Name LIKE 'SQLBI%Methodology' | LEFT( Table[Name], 5 ) = "SQLBI" |
|  | && RIGHT( Table[Name], 11 ) = "Methodology" |
| Name LIKE 'SQLBI%Methodology%' | LEFT( Table[Name], 5 ) = "SQLBI" |
|  | && CONTAINSSTRING( Table[Name], "Methodology" ) |
|  | for PowerPivot v2 or later and Analysis Services 2012/2014/2016/2017: |
|  | LEFT( Table[Name], 5 ) = "SQLBI" |
|  | && SEARCH( "Methodology", Table[Name], 1, 0 ) > 0 |
| Name LIKE '%SQLBI%Methodology%' | CONTAINSSTRING( Table[Name], "SQLBI*Methodology" ) |
|  | for PowerPivot v2 or later and Analysis Services 2012/2014/2016/2017: |
|  | SEARCH( "SQLBI*Methodology", Table[Name], 1, 0 ) > 0 |

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-string-comparison/

Comment: Somehow  - Name LIKE '%SQLBI%'  -- CONTAINSSTRING( Table[Name], "SQLBI" ) does not work in PowerBI.